# Spotlight Culling. Plane vs Cone Shape

Tags: mathematics, lighting, culling

I am building forward + engine based off of partially http://www.humus.name/Articles/PracticalClusteredShading.pdf

If you go to page 36 on the pdf and "spot light culling section" they mention "Do plane-cone test and shrink".[image]

However unlike pseudo code they provided for sphere shape culling, it has no more information.

Thus I am stuck drifting internet trying to find methods to achieve this.

Please guide me to the right direction.

Comment: I'm not sure, are you asking how to derive an efficient plane-cone test?

Comment: @MickLH I am clueless how to start culling process for cone shape(spotlight). I can cull my frustums and planes against sphere but I do not know how to do it against cone shape spotlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Screenshot from : [Real-Time Collision Detection, Volume 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=WGpL6Sk9qNAC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=cone+intersection+with+plane+test&source=bl&ots=Pn5ShG2feR&sig=e5PmVOesQDZxp9KobbHJr15OHeU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvwfCE0PPRAhXLQSYKHdI2Ac44ChDoAQhEMAk#v=onepage&q=cone%20intersection%20with%20plane%20test&f=false)

The collision check is as simple as checking whether vertex of cone and the far end of the cone are lying two difference sides of the plane.

[image]

However in doing so you will end up with either green or purple point depending on the order of your cross product, thus it is important that you check both green and purple to see if the cone is intersection the plane.